# How do I configure shared folders for VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have a Linux host and am setting up a Linux VM in VirtualBox (Ubuntu in both cases). How do I configure shared folders between the host and the VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so, make sure the VirtualBox Guest Additions are already installed (top
menu -> Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD, then follow the prompts)

On the host, go to VirtualBox window:

> top menu -> Devices -> Shared Folders -> Shared Folder Settings

Click "+" icon on right:

- Under "Folder Path" navigate to an absolute pathname on the host like "/home/joe/myFolder"
- Under "Folder Name" enter a unique ID like "someName"

On guest VM, open a terminal and type:

```
> sudo mkdir -p /mystuff
> sudo mount -t vboxsf someName /mystuff
```

The trick is that the ID string "someName" is just a tag to connect the host directory and the VM
directory.  It has not other purpose. The shared folder /home/joe/myFolder is now available as the dir /mystuff in the VM. Note
that the directory name in the VM doesn't have to match the original directory name on the host, although we could make them similar if we wanted (e.g. `/myfolder` or `/joe/myFolder` in the VM).

The VirtualBox GUI does not make a clear distinction between the directory name on the host, the directory
name on the VM, and the ID string that connects them.